# Sort 2-D list with last character's frequancy in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a 2-D list
t = [[3, 3, 3, 'a'], [2, 2, 2, 'b'], [1, 1, 1, 'b']] with each list's last character's frequancy in reverse.
since b is 2 times and a is 1 time so sorted list should be
t_sorted = [[2,2,2,'b'],[1,1,1,'b], [3,3,3,'a']]
I wrote the code:

```
def mine(a):
    return t.count(a[-1])
t = [[3, 3, 3, 'a'], [2, 2, 2, 'b'], [1, 1, 1, 'b']]
print(sorted(t,key = mine, reverse = True))
```

but it is not working fine. what is the right way to do it without using counter python?

Comment: "not working fine": Can you be more specific?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Counter? It seems like *exactly* the right tool for this job. The `.count` solution results in a quadratic time complexity, whereas Counter can be used easily to get a linear complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `t` doesn't have any 'a's or any 'b's. It has lists which include 'a's and 'b's.

Just check it manually:

```
>>> t = [[3, 3, 3, 'a'], [2, 2, 2, 'b'], [1, 1, 1, 'b']]
>>> t.count('a')
0
```

The least confusing way to do it is to just make a (proper) counter of those last elements - let's get only last elements of the sublists and convert it to Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

t = [[3, 3, 3, 'a'], [2, 2, 2, 'b'], [1, 1, 1, 'b']]
my_count = Counter(elem[-1] for elem in t)
```

Now we can use our Counter object to be our position:

```
print(sorted(t,key = lambda x: my_count[x[-1]], reverse = True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an (inferior) solution that doesn't use Counter:

```
def mine(a):
    return [x[-1] for x in t].count(a[-1])
```